# How to decrypt files on the fly when transferring via USB?

Tags: android, encryption, file-transfer

In my Android app I store encrypted files on the SD card and only my app is able to access and decipher them.

However, I need to make those files available for clear transfer to a PC or Mac via the USB connexion.

The idea would be that the user can activate the transfer mode on the app secured by authentication and PIN code. When activated, I would like to create a fake folder tree and files matching the encrypted content on the SD card.

And when the user will try to copy them on his computer, I thought about catching the event and decipher the original file on the fly to allow him to retrieve the original file on his computer's file system.

Does anyone know if that is even technically possible on non-rooted phones?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a USB connection from Android to a computer and then have a client program on the PC and your app on Android talk to each other (no file-system): [Android USB-API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/index.html)
This way, you could transfer the encrypted files and decrypt them on the PC.

Pay attention to the hardware requirements though:

> USB *accessory and host* modes are **directly supported in Android 3.1
>   (API level 12) or newer** platforms. USB *accessory* mode is also
>   **backported to Android 2.3.4 (API level 10)** as an add-on library to support a broader range of devices. Device manufacturers can choose
>   whether or not to include the add-on library on the device's system
>   image.
>
> Note: **Support for USB host and accessory modes are ultimately
>   dependant on the device's hardware, regardless of platform level. You
>   can filter for devices that support USB host** and accessory through a
>   `<uses-feature>` element. See the USB accessory and host documentation
>   for more details.

This would be a low-level implementation.

Comment: That would have been a very good approach and I actually thought about it. But it would implies to have a PC-side client and I've been told it would be impossible due to compagny IT restrictions...